# How to make a user subscribe to an event in facebook using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to users when added to this website event registration also subscribe to the event in the facebook.
The system is already asking for the "create_event" extra permission, I am not finding how to subscribe the user to a particular event after it logged in by graph api. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented in the [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) object page:

```
// RSVP to an Event  
    curl -d "access_token=XXX"  
          https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/{attending|declined}
```

So you need to grant the `rsvp_event` permission.
Example using the php-sdk:

```
$facebook->api("/EVENT_ID/attending", "post", array("access_token" => "XXXXX"));
```

Comment: oh! I didn't understand that the rsvp_event was to subscribe to it. My english kinda poor so I didnt connect "attending" to subscribe to an event. Thanks, I will try right on.

Comment: @Jonathan: I suppose your facebook isn't in english either, right? because there's nothing called subscribe to an event in Facebook.

Comment: yes, it is not in english, so I thought the word to enter an event would be "subscribe". Didn't know that attend could be used to that action either