# Integrating Your Facebook Event to Your Website Without Creating Facebook Application - Possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if it's possible to integrating your facebook event into your own website?
and without creating a facebook application (means, you dont have app id, secret etc - you only have eventid/eid)

and what i'm trying to achieve is:

- my event is a private event means **only invited people can see the event details**
- and I want to list/parse the event wall post, and show it in my website
- is it possible to put attend/maybe/not attend action on my website (any hint/example - much appreciate)
- i want to show/list photo of my events as well

so the application flow more or less would be like this:

once the user come to the site, I'll check

```
if the user logged-in into facebook then
    if user invited to the event then
        full access to the site
        return;
    else
        access denied (sort of)
    end if
else
    show facebook login form / ask the user to login into their facebook account
end if
```

is that possible? and what is the effective way to achieve it? should i create FB application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. ***You need a Facebook Application***
2. **You** should grant the `user_events,offline_access` permissions and save your event ID and access token somewhere (*this would answer your second point of listing event's wall post*)
3. Now that you are able to list your event's data, **users** should authorize and grant your application the `create_event` permission.
4. Then refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861870/how-to-make-a-user-subscribe-to-an-event-in-facebook-using-graph-api/4862126#4862126) to check how to rsvp a user (`access_token` here is the user's access token not the one **you** got from `offline_access`)

*Please note that I don't guaranty the result of the above depending on your event privacy setting, so the best thing to do is test it.*