# "Facebook Graph API" attendee status on Facebook Events

Tags: ios, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

How can i set the a person's attendee status on Facebook Events (e.g. attending, maybe, or declined). ?

I found "rsvp_event" permission. But dont see any Graph REST call to this action.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/maybe/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/declined/

Unless i misunderstood your question, those are the API endpoints. You can only read them though: "You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.".

Although, you can just try with the suggestion in this thread: [How to make a user subscribe to an event in facebook using Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861870/how-to-make-a-user-subscribe-to-an-event-in-facebook-using-graph-api)